# Python numpy floating point array precision

Tags: python, numpy, svm, precision

I am trying to solve for SVM optimisation problem using Pegasos mini-batch algorithm (as in Fig 2) from this link:  http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/ShalevSiSrCo10.pdf

```
#X: m*n matrix with m examples and n features per example (m=4000 and n=784 in my case), Y: m length vector containing 1 or -1 for each example, l: lambda as given in algorithm (l=1 in my code), itr: number of iterations, k: size of batch (100) in my case
def pegasos(X,Y,l,n,m,itr,k):
w = np.zeros((1,n),dtype=np.float32)
print m, n
diff = 0.0
for t in range(1,itr+1):
    A = random.sample(range(1,m),k)
    total = np.zeros((1,n),dtype=np.float32)
    eta = 1/(l*t)
    for i in A:
        x = X[i]
        y = Y[i]
        p = y*(np.dot(w,x.T))
        if p < 1:
            p1 = y*x
            total = np.add(total,p1)
    #update rule
    w = np.add((w*(1-(1/t))) , (eta*total*(1/k)))
return w
```

My dataset is in such a way that when my variable *total* is computed, I get mostly 0s but there are a few values in the order of 10^(-1) to 10^(-5). As soon as total is multiplied by (eta/k) at the update rule, all the values become 0. and hence at every iteration the w I obtain is 0. which should not be the case. I have tried ways to increase the precision of my floats but they don't seem to work at all. When I use basic Pegasos algorithm (as given in Fig 1 in the above link), I don't face any problem, thus my dataset is not utterly weird. 
Any help regarding this issue would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: which python version? Could you split the first long line? (one line per variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need precision, you should use `np.float64` (the normal floating point precision `double`).

If you are using Python 2, you are using integer divition in `(1/t)`, `(1/k)`, and `(1/l)`. Write it as `1.0/`, to force a floating point division.

Comment: Yes, that works. I am pretty new to python and wasn't aware of  this. Thank you! :)

Comment: @coder_91: it is a common problem, so Python3 makes automatically float division. I think nobody really understand the reason than Python2 changed it to integer division (if operand are integer). Python1 is analog to python3, so less error prone.

Comment: I am working on Python2 that's the reason I was caught up in this tiny issue. I guess I should upgrade to Python3 to avoid running into such issues further.